# VS 2015 - How to generate a references.js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

So I deleted my references.js file and I was wondering how to automatically create one via VS.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually create it with the correct name (_references.js), then right-click the file and select Update Javascript references.

This file must (by default) be located in a folder at the root called /scripts/.

You can change the location, see [this article](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) for instructions how and the backstory on _references.js

Comment: Looks like you may need to open the file first in order for the Update JavaScript References option appears in the context menu